# aframe draw component not work with new aframe version 0.8.2

Tags: canvas, aframe

I'm using aframe 0.7.0 version with `aframe-draw-component`
https://codepen.io/sky790312/pen/VVvNWJ

It works fine to draw on the a-sky element. But aframe 0.7.0 version has gyroscope bug in the mobile device.
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3565

So I update aframe to 0.8.2 version. But it can't work now. (change the codepen aframe version, you will see.)

But if I put the `acanvas` to "a-plane" element, it works fine. (It just can't work on "a-sky").

Is there any idea about aframe draw component with the new aframe version !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working properly (try it with an `a-box`), the `a-sky` just has it's side flipped.

Since you're overriding the material, setting `material="side: both"` isn't working.
You need to set the THREE material.side property in your component, the most simple way being:

```
this.el.getObject3D("mesh").material.side = 1
```

Check it out [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aQmLLj). A bit blurry, but cool anyway :)

Comment: Thanks, It works! But I find another issue that ios safari/chrome will not show anything :( Any idea?

Comment: I think it's my code's problem not the codepen example. Thanks!